# Why I received type mismatch error when running elseif statement

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, type-mismatch

So I am trying to run the following code but received 'Type mismatch error" for line `ElseIf Cells(x, 1) <> "" And Cells(x, 2) <> "" And Cells(x, 15).Value <= 0 Then`. I am guessing it is something to do with the `if` statement that is not nested properly within the `for` and `next`statement. But they are all seem fine. I have spent hours on this trying to debug but to no avail. Who can tell me what goes wrong with my code?

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 4 To 100
    If Cells(x, 1) <> "" And Cells(x, 2) <> "" And Cells(x, 6).Value <= 0 Then                  
        Cells(x, 16).Value = 6
        Cells(x, 17).Value = -0.3179688

    ElseIf Cells(x, 1) <> "" And Cells(x, 2) <> "" And Cells(x, 15).Value <= 0 Then '(*Received error for this line)
        Cells(x, 16).Value = 1
        Cells(x, 17).Value = 0.6820312

    ElseIf Cells(x, 5) = "" or Cells(x, 6) <> "" or Cells(x, 7) <> "" Then '(*Still Received error for this line)
        Cells(x, 16).Value = ""
        Cells(x, 17).Value = ""   

    ElseIf Cells(x, 1).Value = "A. Agriculture, forestry and fishing" Then

        Select Case LCase(Cells(x, 2).Value)
            Case "all", "id", "sg"
                Select Case Cells(x, 15).Value
                    Case Is > 4
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 5
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = -0.2405524
                    Case 2.01 To 4
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 4
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = 0.0223717
                    Case 1.01 To 2
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 3
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = 0.112231
                    Case 0.01 To 1
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 2
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = 0.5928195
                End Select
            Case "my", "th"
                Select Case Cells(x, 15).Value
                    Case Is > 4.5
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 5
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = -0.2405524
                    Case 2.01 To 4.5
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 4
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = 0.0223717
                    Case 1.01 To 2
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 3
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = 0.112231
                    Case 0.01 To 1
                        Cells(x, 16).Value = 2
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = 0.5928195
                End Select
            Case ""
                Cells(x, 16).Value = ""
                Cells(x, 17).Value = ""
        End Select
    End if

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: What is in `Cells(x, 15).Value`?

Comment: @Bernie, it contains an existing formula of `=(D4+E4)F4` in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Okay ... and what's in those cells? If you have a string, then checking <= 0 will throw a type error. Try checking to see if it is actually a number before doing the comparison.

Comment: I noticed what causes the problem. Code runs totally fine if all cells in 
`=(D4+E4)F4`are filled. But if any of them is left blank, I got this mismatch error. What code should I put in so that if anyone of these three cells is not filled, `cells(x,15)`will return nothing, and would not give me error?

Comment: Edited to leave `cells(x,15)`blank when D4,E4 or F4 are not filled but the second elseif  still gives an error.

Comment: Finally problem solved. Figured out on my own. Thanks anyway @user1274820

Comment: Sorry for missing the replies

Comment: @tnkh, please add your answer below as an actual answer and mark it as accepted.  That helps others in the future.

Comment: @Byron Wall, edited my code and it works.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for adding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edited my code and it works.

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 4 To 100

   If Cells(x, 2).Value = "" Or Cells(x, 3).Value = "" Or Cells(x, 5).Value = "" Or Cells(x, 6).Value = "" Or Cells(x, 7).Value = "" Then
                       Cells(x, 17).Value = ""
                       Cells(x, 18).Value = ""

                    ElseIf Cells(x, 7).Value <= 0 Then
                       Cells(x, 17).Value = 6
                       Cells(x, 18).Value = -0.3179688

                    ElseIf Cells(x, 16).Value <= 0 Then
                        Cells(x, 17).Value = 1
                        Cells(x, 18).Value = 0.6820312

                    ElseIf Cells(x, 2).Value = "A. Agriculture, forestry and fishing" Then
                        Select Case LCase(Cells(x, 3).Value)
                            Case "all", "id", "sg"
                                    Select Case Cells(x, 16).Value
                                        Case Is > 4
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 5
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = -0.2405524
                                        Case 2.01 To 4
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 4
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = 0.0223717
                                        Case 1.01 To 2
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 3
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = 0.112231
                                        Case 0.01 To 1
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 2
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = 0.5928195
                                    End Select
                            Case "my", "th"
                                    Select Case Cells(x, 16).Value
                                        Case Is > 4.5
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 5
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = -0.2405524
                                        Case 2.01 To 4.5
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 4
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = 0.0223717
                                        Case 1.01 To 2
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 3
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = 0.112231
                                        Case 0.01 To 1
                                            Cells(x, 17).Value = 2
                                            Cells(x, 18).Value = 0.5928195
                                    End Select
                        End Select
End if

Next x
```